# How to get menu items from one menu and append them to different menu

Tags: javascript, menu

I have a mini menu with few links which on tablet and mobile screen sizes have to be hidden which  is fine am doing this with css and media queries, but I have one more main menu with different links and on normal screen sizes appear as expanded but on tablet and mobile appear as a hidden clickable hamburger menu. I want on tablet and mobile size when the links from the mini menu are hidden to become part of the main menu. I know I have to create in my .js file some kind of for loop which on tablet and mobile sizes will grab the menu items from the minu menu and append them to the main menu but not really sure how to do that if someone please can help me with a code wireframes how to do that will be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add all the relevant code to the question, ideally using a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to just put inside your main menu the links which you want to be seen on mobile and add a class to those links which will only show them on mobile. If it's just a simple link it should do the job.

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>always visible<li>

  <li>always visible<li>

  <li class="visible-mobile">only visible on mobile<li>

  <li>always visible<li>
</ul>
```

Then in your css:

```
.main-menu .visible-mobile { display: none }

@media (max-width: ...) {
   .main-menu .visible-mobile { display: block }     
}
```

If you still prefer to do it with javascript, here's one way to do it

```
const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.main-menu');
const minuMenu = document.querySelector('.mini-menu');
const mobileBreakpoint = 767; // put your mobile breakpoint here
const isMobile = window.innerWidth < mobileBreakpoint; 

if ( isMobile ) {
    const listItems = miniMenu.querySelectorAll('li');
    mainMenu.appendChild(listItems);
}
```